# dependent or independent t test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

Suppose I have a dataset with 1,000 people and they rating 5 shampoos across a number of attributes (cost, smell, texture, how well it cleans).

If I wanted to compare the average of an attribute across brands, would I use an independent t-test? I know that multiple comparisons invite things like a Bonferroni correction, but is it appropriate to use an independent t-test here? I know I should probably do an ANOVA, but really basic, if I wanted to see if the mean for shampoo A on clean was bigger than the mean for shampoo B, would I see an independent or dependent test? And why?

You can think of the dataset as long instead of very wide, with a set of rows for each respondentXbrand combination. Then can I think of the data as multiple independent samples?

Comment: I'd do a paired t test here.

Comment: @gammer you really should explain the rationale for your use of a paired t-test (dependent sample t-test).

Comment: @MichaelLew, assuming we're talking about the same samples, the point estimate of the difference would be the same no matter which test you did, and the paired t-test almost always more powerful than the 2-sample t-test

Comment: @gammer I agree, and besides being more powerful, the df for paired t test would be correct.

Comment: OP: this thread http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38102/paired-versus-unpaired-t-test is about whether to use a paired or unpaired test. The question is good and some (but not all) of the answers there are good.